# update data in database using selected data in option

Tags: php

I have a html form where I display all the list of candidates using dropdown or option. All data of option are comes from the database. Here:

```
<form method ="post" action="">
<div class="gov-align">
<div class="hero-body-candidate_gov">
<font color="black">Candidate for Governor</font>
</div>
<div class="governor">
<div class="gov-margin">
<?php 
$governor= "SELECT a.cand_id, cand_Lname, cand_Fname,     cand_partylist,cand_position, image FROM cand_info as a INNER JOIN cand_account as b ON a.cand_id=b.cand_id INNER JOIN cand_position as c ON b.cand_id=c.cand_id WHERE cand_position = 'President'";
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$governor);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ $governor_id=$row['cand_id']; ?>
<img class="gov" src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" width="150" height="150" border="0" onmouseover="showtrail('<?php echo $row['image'];?>','<?php echo   $row['cand_Fname']." ".$row['cand_Lname'];?> ',200,5)" onmouseout="hidetrail()">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


 <?php
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="select_gov">
<div class="margin-gov">
<select name="governor" class="span222">
<option class="option">--Select Candidate--</option>
<?php
$governor= "SELECT a.cand_id, cand_Lname, cand_Fname, cand_partylist,cand_position FROM cand_info as a INNER JOIN cand_account as b ON a.cand_id=b.cand_id INNER JOIN cand_position as c ON b.cand_id=c.cand_id WHERE cand_position = 'President'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$governor);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ $governor_id=$row['cand_id']; ?>

 <option name="" value="<?php echo $row['cand_id'] ?>" class="option"><?php    echo $row['cand_Fname']." ".$row['cand_Lname']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail_widget">

 <div class="submit-vote">

<button id="submit"  id="vote" class="btn btn-success" name="submit"><i class="icon-thumbs-up icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Submit Vote</button>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is php line below that html.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$gov        =  isset($_['cand_id']) ? $_POST['cand_id'] : '';
$sql1="UPDATE cand_votecount SET votecount = votecount + 1 WHERE cand_id = '$gov'";

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
?>
</form>
```

I want to add one for candidate's votecount that the student choosed. Whenever I click submit it only refresh and nothing happen.

PS. I know my code can easily inject sql injection. no need for comment about  that.

Comment: what is `votecount + 1` where you define??

Comment: Have you mentioned your entire form HTML code? If so, it's missing the form close tag and the submit button.

Comment: votecount is the row in my database

Comment: @ObjectManipulator the form close tag is in the bottom of php code and sorry, I forgot to include the button submit.

Answer (score 0):

Do a small change

```
if(isset($_POST['governor']))
{
$sql1="UPDATE cand_votecount SET votecount = votecount + 1 WHERE cand_id =".$_POST['governor'];
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
```

Comment: still not updating.

Comment: Opps!! sorry.. but where you end form without form and submit button how can it will submit?ok ok i will  correct it @Pardz

Comment: i updated my post with close tag for form and submit button.

Comment: where is form close tag bro? @Pardz